# Format text alignment within Bokehs HoverTool/tooltips - Python

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have the hover function on in Pandas Bokehs.

How do I justify the text to the left hand side of the box rather than the right? See the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJOiV.png)

This is my current code for my tooltips

```
tooltips=[('Time','@{Time}'), ('Propeller, Fx [kN]','@{Propeller, Fx [kN]}{1.1}')\
            ,('Engine RPM [rpm]','@{Engine RPM [rpm]}{1.1}')\
            ,('Fwd. Velocity, u [knots]', '@{Fwd. Velocity, u [knots]}{1.1}')]
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic convenience auto-tooltip always and only ever formats as shown in the image. If you want something more sophisticated, you would use a [custom tooltip](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#custom-tooltip), which allows you to supply a small HTML template to format things however you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will take a look at it.